# Printing next line with sed

Tags: sed

I want to print next line of matching word with sed.

I tried this command but it gives error :

```
sed -n '/<!\[CDATA\[\]\]>/ { N p}/' test.xml
```

Comment: You need a semicolon between "N" and "p": `{N;p}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

what about `grep -e -A 1` regex? It will print line below regex.

With sed, looking for pattern "dd", below works fine as you would:

```
sed -n '/dd/ {n;p}' file
```

For file content:

```
dd
aa
ss
aa
```

It prints:

```
aa
```

Answer (score 3):

use awk

```
awk '/pattern/{getline;print}' file
```

Comment: `/bin/gawk` is about 6 times larger than `/bin/sed` on Linux. On other OSes the ratio is similar, even if the `awk` is not from GNU...