# How can I use sed to match between two patterns and get the next line after the second pattern?

Tags: sed

I'm familiar with using sed to grab lines between two patterns. For example:

```
$ cat file
A
PATTERN1
B
PATTERN2
C
$ sed -n '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/p' file
PATTERN1
B
PATTERN2
```

What I'd like to do, however, is generate this output:

```
PATTERN1
B
PATTERN2
C
```

I've come across the {n;p} syntax ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820802/printing-next-line-with-sed)), but I can't seem to shoehorn this into the type of pattern matching I'm doing in this example problem.

Comment: `sed -En '/PATTERN1|PATTERN2/{N;p}' file`?

Comment: @Cyrus interesting trick.. will fail only if there's no line between the two markers

Comment: ... and it fails if there is more than one line between `PATTERN1` and `PATTERN2`. It only works in that one particular case chad512 described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `N` (syntax here is based on `GNU sed`)

```
$ sed -n '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/{/PATTERN2/N; p}' ip.txt 
PATTERN1
B
PATTERN2
C
```

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '/PATTERN1/{f=1} f || (c && c--); /PATTERN2/{f=0; c=1}' ip.txt
PATTERN1
B
PATTERN2
C
```

which you can generalize using:

```
awk -v n=2 '/PATTERN1/{f=1} f || (c && c--); /PATTERN2/{f=0; c=n}'
```

**Further Reading:**

- [How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or)
- [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/{p;/PATTERN2/{n;p}}' file
```

Alternative:

```
sed '/PATTERN1/{:a;n;/PATTERN2/!ba;n;p};d' file
```